# Android SIP - Failed to create Sip Session

Tags: android, sip

I'm trying to make a call from android using the Android SIP API.
I followed [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) and a few more similar guides.
When i call the function

```
SipManager.makeAudioCall(String localProfileUri, String peerProfileUri, SipAudioCall.Listener listener, int timeout)
```

I get the Exception **"Failed to create SipSession; network available?"**.
I found some ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11777627) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692868/android-voip-sipexception-failed-to-create-sipsession) answers but none of them solved the problem.

Comment: ur credentials may be wrong

Comment: The credentials are OK. I've checked that on a softphone I've downloaded from Google play.

Comment: I have the same problem, can verify credentials are okay by makeing/receiving calls in several other apps. I tried what other users suggested and added a delay to allow SIP to initialize, no luck. Can you post more of your code? Like your SIP builder?

Comment: My problem was that the WiFi signal was to low for creating a sip session.
U can try this link to check if that is your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206891/android-how-to-monitor-wifi-signal-strengthin.